# Adding date in the x-axis usig flot graph

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, graph, flot

The code I am using is below.
I want to make a simple graph based on the data from my database table.
It is working now but I want date on the bottom axis is not appearing properly. 
while the value of variable is

```
[25-03-15, 1236], [26-03-15, 3000], [27-03-15, 3054], [30-03-15, 4000]
```

that is right. But I cant get this date on the x-axis. any solution there? 
The way I am getting getting this value is

```
<?php 
$usd=$this->db->query('select transaction_date, SUM(amount) as total from transactions GROUP BY transaction_date')->result_array();
$str = '';
for($i=0; $i<count($usd); $i++){
    if($i!=0){
        $str = $str.', ['.date('d-m-y', strtotime($usd[$i]["transaction_date"])).', '.$usd[$i]["total"].']';
    }else{
        $str = $str.'['.date('d-m-y', strtotime($usd[$i]["transaction_date"])).', '.$usd[$i]["total"].']';
    }
}

echo $str;


?>
```

Then I pass this data in java script like this:

```
var graphData = [{

        data: [ <?php echo $str; ?>]
    }
];
```

But At the end I can not get the date on x axis.

PS:
I am working on the view of codeigniter application.

Comment: Is there any label on the x axis now?

Comment: no there is no label on x-axis, In code there is only tickcolor and ticksize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) for time series data.

You need javascript timestamps. In PHP you get them simply with

```
strtotime($usd[$i]["transaction_date"]) * 1000
```

Then your data should look like this:

```
[1427238000000, 1236], [1427324400000, 3000], ...
```

For the labels on the x axis, use the `timeformat` options to get back the format you want:

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%d-%m-%y"
}
```

Comment: 23, 1236], [19, 3000], [13, 3054], [19, 4000]
 this is the data that is not what i needed and not working. any thing else please